# ssh'ing into mac, home and end insert a tilde

Tags: macos, ssh

When I ssh into my Mac using PuTTY from Windows, and I try to move to the beginning or end of a line by pressing Home or End, it inserts a Tilde (~) character under the cursor instead. This is highly frustrating. Is there some way to fix this? The Mac doesn't seem to have an .inputrc file in /etc so it's not clear to me that it would use one.

The shell I am using is Bash, and the version of OSX is El Capitan (10.11.6).

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS X version do you have, and more importantly, what shell does it use (bash, zsh, ...)?

Comment: el capitan, bash

Comment: Check to see if you can replicate this behavior by sshing into other accounts on the mac. If you find that this does not happen when you're logged in as a different user, your problem may lie in your ~/.inputrc file. You could try deleting it or, preferably, renaming it to see if this corrects your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the inputrc from my Debian machine to /etc/inputrc on my Mac and it works now.